# How to work around shell limitation of 'Argument list too long'?

Tags: bash, centos, wildcards

How can I work around the bash shell limitation of 'Argument list too long' when using filename wildcards that match a ton of files in /tmp/?

```
[my-centos4 tmp] rm -rf /tmp/myLocalFiles*
bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in myLocalFiles*; do rm -f $i; done`

Answer (score 3):

This is a little simpler than jáquer suggested:

```
find /tmp -name "myLocalFiles*" -delete
```

Comment: My 'find' on centos4 does not support the -delete option.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Then your `find` probably also does not support `find ... -exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp -name "myLocalFiles*" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't use -delete to find command, this also works:

```
find /tmp -name "myLocalFiles*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: from #bash channel: "xargs(1) is dangerous (broken, exploitable, etc.) when reading non-NUL-delimited input. If you're working with filenames, use `find's -exec  [command] {}` + instead or `-print0 | xargs -0` provided you don't care about portability and like doing unnecessary extra work. Othwerwise a nice `for` loop."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wines `cmd`

```
wine cmd
del "Z:\tmp\myLocalFiles*"
exit
```

Shell expansion works great but it has some caveats. The Windows convention never suffers from these problems, but places the duty on the programmer. This is probably better, since the writer of the shell cannot know how any program expects its input data.