# How do I avoid "Argument list too long" errors when compressing thousands of files?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 200,000 XML files in the folder on a RHEL7 Linux server.  I need to zip all 200,000 XML  files. I am using the Tar command but getting the error "Argument list too long" is there any other way in this 200,000 need zip only 10,000

```
tar -cvf xml.tar *.xml
```

All xml files need to be archived separately as individual archive that has original file name in the archive name.

Original files:

```
1.xml
2.xml
...
n.xml
```

Result of archiving OP wants:

```
1.xml.tgz
2.xml.tgz
...
n.xml.tgz
```

Comment: While I edited in the command verbatim from a now-deleted comment by OP, apparently that's not the case. OP's comments from a now-deleted `tar` answer: "*its working but all the files ziped and genarated into single folder i need zip each and every file : Example : filename .xml its convert in to filename1 .xml .zip*" and "*sorry i need to ".zip"*".

Comment: kesavanagaprasadthonta, please clarify: do you mean you *ran* the `tar` command, but you don't actually want a `tar` file? And do you want individual `zip`s or `gzip`s? They are different formats, and require different commands.

Comment: @Bob shell simply choke on a huge list of files in command line when OP used `*.xml`

Comment: IMHO making a big single TAR you are going to reproduce the problem somewhere else. Directories with over 10K files are always a problem. It could be much more practical to make TARs of a few thousands files each.

Comment: @Bob Maybe you shouldn't have deleted your answer yet. Now we have a new answer about `tar` that is IMHO not as good as yours.

Comment: [Is there any limit on number of file name we can pass in tar](https://superuser.com/q/935102/241386), [zip: Argument list too long (80.000 files in overall)](https://superuser.com/q/272696/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [zip: Argument list too long (80.000 files in overall)](https://superuser.com/questions/272696/zip-argument-list-too-long-80-000-files-in-overall)

Comment: @phuclv OP wants to archive each file individually, so here he got two problems - "Argument list too long" and compressing files individually, so it doesn't looks like duplicate

Comment: @Alex the rare deleted comments from the OP were too obscure and hard understand. But if it's about separate archive files then there are already a lot of other duplicates: [How to work around shell limitation of 'Argument list too long'?](https://superuser.com/q/240183/241386), [Argument list too long](https://superuser.com/q/282533/241386), [argument list too long for rm -rf *, 4000 files](https://superuser.com/q/391811/241386)... Just replace the corresponding command with zip/tar/whatever

Comment: @phuclv I think OP has a serious language barrier, that's why I patient to him

Comment: Note: archiving separate files into `.tgz` makes questionable sense. It's a two-step process: `tar` + `gzip`. Tarring a single file makes no sense; to compress one file at a time `gzip` is enough. Use `gzip`, unless you explicitly need `.tgz` format (e.g. to process these files in the exact same manner as other `.tgz` files where the `tar` part makes sense).

Answer (score 2):

You exceeded maximum command line length. Command line has finite length that you can test with `getconf ARG_MAX` command. When you running shell command that includes glob pattern such as `*` in directory that contain huge amount of files then command line is overfilled and one will receive error message "Argument list too long", so it isn't a `tar` problem. Keep this it in mind when you use other commands with glob patterns that applied to huge amount files.

To resolve your issue, you can use `find` program that will "walk"
through the directory and feed `tar`.

To archive all files as a single compressed tar archive you can use:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print | tar -czvf xml.tgz -T -
```

To archive all files individually as compressed tar archives(*not really sure why need to by tar'ed if it's a single file, but as you wish*), use

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec tar -czvf '{}'.tgz '{}' \;
```

To archive all files individually as gzip archives, use:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec gzip '{}' \;
```

Be warned, command above will remove original files (!!!)

To archive all files individually as zip archives, use:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec zip '{}'.zip '{}' \;
```

P.S. I added also missed(?) option to compress tar archive.

Comment: `find . -name ' *.xml' | tar -T -` would work just as well?

Comment: @xenoid Doesn't looks like it would work

Comment: @Alex Very nice, I didn't know tar can also use a list from pipe. I have been using things like `find . -name "*.xml" -print | zip xml.zip -@` for zip archive

Comment: @BernardWei I glad you found it useful. You probably might want to post your solution here too, since it not clear if OP wants a `zip` or `tar` archive.

Comment: @Bernadwe need to Zip each and every xml

Comment: @BernardWei thank you but all files generated  in single zip files but i need each file suppurate zip Example: demo.xml.gz

Comment: @kesavanagaprasadthonta I updated my post, I think you can find there all solutions you need

Comment: @kesavanagaprasadthonta make up your mind! It seems from the above comment you want `*.xml` -> `*.xml.zip` and now you say `*.xml.gz`. And what is it about `*.xml.tgz`? Moreover `zip` and `gzip` (beside bzip2) are very different. There's no option to `zip` directly from `tar`. If you want separate files why don't say it clearly? Read [ask] or you'll just get more downvotes

Comment: @kesavanagaprasadthonta Any reason why are you creating multiple tar archive of a single file each?